# How to transform skew only towards bottom corners?

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

I'm confused about how can I transform the corners in one side (top or bottom) only something like below:

Normal:

[image]

Transformed:

[image]

Can anyone please help me on this? Here, the top corners stay same and the bottom corners are transformed. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with something like this, clean and simple without multiple `div`s.

```css
#trapezium {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 50px;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-45deg);
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id='trapezium'></div>
```

Comment: This has one corner. I need two corners (bottom left, bottom right).

Comment: Check now! I have updated my code.

Comment: I need transformation.

Comment: You mean the design should be flipover? the small sides should be at bottom?

Comment: Yes, but with transform trick. (What you have shown in demo is correct but I need same effect with transform css)

Comment: sorry it took time to understand the requirement! let me know now.

Answer (score 1):

you can have similar output using [perspective](https://3dtransforms.desandro.com/perspective) and `transform:  rotateX(-45deg);` CSS attribute, here is a working snippet:

```css
.scene {
  position: relative;
  left:100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  margin: 40px;
  /* perspective property */
  perspective: 400px;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  transform:  rotateX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="scene">
  <div class="panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. But what do you mean by transformY? Ah, it can't be done to just one div?

Comment: sorry I meant `rotateX()` will update my answer.